# Dual DB Connectivity in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I have a web application which uses an Oracle DB as the back end data source. This Oracle DB instance is being refreshed daily and while its being refreshed we have to switch to another DB (a copy of the original DB) seamlessly  and while the other DB (copy) is being refreshed it should fall back to the original Oracle DB.

We are using Spring JDBC.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: If you are going to down-vote please leave a comment

Comment: I don't know who down voted me for asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since DevOps related solution was not agreed by the management I had to go ahead with **[AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html)** based implementation.

The solution is simple, all you have to do is extends the [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) and provide a routing criteria by overriding **[determineCurrentLookupKey()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html#determineCurrentLookupKey--)** method.

Your Customized Data source will look like this

```
public class ResourceAwareMyDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourceAwareMyDataSource.class);

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {

        try {
            //Check whether the primary DB is active 
            if(primaryIsActive()) {
                return "Primary"
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error occurred when checking  primary",e);
            logger.info("Switching back to Secondary..");
            return "Secondary";
        }
        //Primary is inactive
        logger.info("Primary is Inactive, Switching back to Secondary");
        return "Secondary";
    }
}
```

This will be your Java configuration for the above data source

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("myCustomizedDataSource")
public DataSource resourceAwareMyDataSource() {

    ResourceAwareMyDataSource dataSource = new ResourceAwareMyDataSource ();
    Map<Object, Object> targetDataSourcesMap = new HashedMap();
    targetDataSourcesMap.put("Primary", getPrimaryDataSource());
    targetDataSourcesMap.put("Secondary", getSecondaryDataSource());
    dataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSourcesMap);
    return dataSource;
}
```

As usual your primary and secondary data source will look like this, Here I am providing tow basic data sources to connect to primary and secondary

```
public DataSource getPrimaryDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(...);
    dataSource.setUrl(...);
    dataSource.setUsername(...);
    dataSource.setPassword(...);
    dataSource.setValidationQuery(...);
    return dataSource;
}

public DataSource getSecondaryDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(...);
    dataSource.setUrl(...);
    dataSource.setUsername(...);
    dataSource.setPassword(...);
    dataSource.setValidationQuery(....);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will largely depend on what your requirements are. I would use Dev-ops for this. How Dev-ops you want to get is up to you. Just a comment too every time I see a question such as switching databases in Spring, or remaking a singleton bean, etc. The developer is always doing something very strange, often because they think they have a certain requirement, but they don't really.

There are Dev-ops tools out there to have read-only clones of a database, which can be updated from another source at a frequency of whatever you want. There is no need to switch to another database as this is happening. (Also check out the pattern whereby there are many read-only clones of a database, and one 'true' database, where all the writes are redirected to)

Even if this didn't meet your requirements then you could use Dev-ops to visualize the port and database URL etc and redirect it wherever and whenever you want. I would also kill all the sessions in between this jump, but that's just me.

Using Dev-ops will keep this sort of stuff out of the code in your Spring Web-app so it stays clean and the code doesn't need to change as this requirement changes. It will be nasty working with a project that has this stuff hard coded into it, I advise you think cautiously about what road you will take. If you do go down Dev-ops then you won't have these issues.

Comment: Actually I pointed that when this was asked, unfortunately it is not an options( at least as of now). What I am looking is some Connection Pooling related solution (something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520255/can-i-use-one-pooled-datasource-for-multiple-databases-with-spring-hibernate-c3p), PS - I am not going to down vote you as your answer is a valid one

Comment: The comment was directed at whoever down-voted you, not at you lol. I don't know your situation, or if you have tried. But I think you should try and sell the dev-ops solution. Otherwise you may as well re-deploy your webapp with the different settings.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Really appreciate it.